# How to make a dynamic line in flutter flame forge2d?

Tags: flutter, flame, forge2d

I want to make it possible to draw a physical line like here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cEU5.gif)

But I don't know how to make a dynamic line in flume forge2d.

I tried to make ChainShape(), but it can't be BodyType.dynamic.
So I tried to make a PolygonShape(), but it can only be convex.
So I tried to make a lot of CircleShape() and connect them with a hard link between them
And this is what I got

```
final bodyDef = BodyDef(
      userData: this,
      position: Vector2(worldSize.x / 2, 5.0),
      type: BodyType.dynamic,

    );

    final shape = CircleShape()..radius = .05;
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(shape)
      ..density = 1.1
      ..friction = 0.5
      ..filter = filter
      ..restitution = 0.0;
    return world.createBody(bodyDef)
      ..createFixture(fixtureDef)
      ..angularVelocity = radians(0);
```

```
final List<Ball> balls = [];
    final double initialX = 1.5;
    final double initialY = 4;
    final double spacing = 0.02;
    double x = initialX;
    double y = initialY;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      final ball = Ball();
      balls.add(ball);
      await world.add(ball);
      ball.body.setType(BodyType.dynamic);
   

      if (i > 20){
        y = initialY - (i - 20) * spacing;
      } else {
        x = initialX + i * spacing;
      }

      ball.body.setTransform(Vector2(x, y), 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < balls.length - 1; i++) {
      final weldJointDef = WeldJointDef()
        ..initialize(balls[i].body, balls[i + 1].body, balls[i].position)
      ..dampingRatio = 0
      ..frequencyHz = 0
      ..collideConnected = false;
      world.createJoint(WeldJoint(weldJointDef));
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxoWc.gif)
But that's not what I need.
it's like a jelly-like compound

Сould you please guide me on how can I make a line that has dynamic properties?